# Fragment Layout In Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, visual-studio, xamarin

I just want to create a two columns in the same content at main. Listview for the left column and frame layout for the right column. The content of frame layout would be replace of fragment. It looks like this picture:

[image: This is the picture]

But there is problem in my work. The text in my fragment content exceeds in the main frame layout. I don't if there is something wrong with my axml or with my C# codes. But when I clicked the `list<string>` of my listView, its working fine. But the text is exceeding from the layout. This is the picture of my error:

[image: This is the picture]

This is my main.axml codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#818181"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:background="#E3F2FD" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

This is my mainactivity.cs codes:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Java.Util;
using SupportToolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using SupportFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace testing_code
{
    [Activity(Label = "testing_code", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.DesignDemo")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private SupportToolbar mToolbar;
        private List<string> mleftdata;
        private ListView list1;
        private ArrayAdapter<string> madapter;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            mToolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

            list1 = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview1);

            mleftdata = new List<string>();

            mleftdata.Add("number 1");
            mleftdata.Add("number 2");
            madapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mleftdata);

            list1.Adapter = madapter;

            list1.ItemClick += List1_ItemClick;

            LoadFragment(0);

        }


        void LoadFragment(int id)
        {
            SupportFragment fragment = null;
            switch (id)
            {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Fragment2();
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment == null)
                return;

            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
                .Commit();
        }

        private void List1_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //Intent myIntent;
            //switch (e.Position)
            //{
            //    case 0:
            //        myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
            //        StartActivity(myIntent);
            //        break;
            //}

            LoadFragment(e.Position);

        }


    }
}
```

---

This is my fragment2.axml code for number 2 in my listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="This is my sample.... But the text is exceed in the fragment content!"
     android:textSize="30sp"
      android:textColor="#333333"
      android:layout_gravity="top" />
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

---

And this is my fragment2.cscode for number 2 in my listview:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using SupportFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.App;

namespace testing_code
{
    public class Fragment2 : SupportFragment
    {

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here

        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_layout2, container, false);




            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, the [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) ViewGroup will add its child to the left-top of itself by default, but you can use `layout_toRightOf` or `layout_toLeftOf` and others to control its children's position.

In your `main.axml` file, add :

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/listview1"
```

In the `FrameLayout` tag.

So the `RelativeLayout` tag should like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#818181"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#E3F2FD" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/listview1"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved my problem :). It takes a week and then nothing happen but with this solution. Thank you very much you solved it :). Now i can move to the part of my work project :)